# Avoid trial field test using previous data: use of chi-squared test to show that carcass removal do not change significantly over time

Tags: r, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, model, biostatistics

I am implicated on the analysis of mortality rates of bats and birds in wind farms.
For this purpose, I need to go to the field and count the number of carcasses found around the turbines. However, this number should be corrected using two variables:

- observer efficiency;
- carcass persistence (scavengers could remove the carcass from the original site)

Aiming to estimate these variables, a field trial should be performed using hundreds of domestic animal carcasses, ie chickens and chicks.
I already have data from field trials from 2016 to 2020. My idea is to avoid the unnecessary use of chickens in the trials, showing to the contractor that the carcass persistence do not change significantly over the time. For that, **I would like to do chi-squared test over the raw numbers of removed and not removed carcasses in each year.**
With respect to observer efficiency, we already have this data for my team.
If carcass persistence does not change over time, I would like to test the model using the numbers of the previous years. Any idea how I could do it? How could I test if the mortality rates do not change significantly over the years using the model trained with all the data of persistence.
Here is the link of the R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/carcass/carcass.pdf

Comment: Well, not quite. One cannot demonstrate a lack of change without fear of contradiction, that means that a change that is not significantly different is not significant. One can however establish confidence intervals for differences, and that then is the proper approach.

Comment: Carl, thank you very much for your feedback. Once I train my model using all previous data of carcass persistance (2016-2020), how could I test if this model is "good" in relation to models created for each year? Probably the confidence intervals of mortalities are going to be overlap when I compare for example the year 2020 trained with persistance rate of 2020 vs the year 202 trained with persistance rates from all years. I mean, how could I know that the differences are acceptable?

Comment: That depends on exactly what you did. For example, if you tested exactly 100 chicken carcasses for 20 years for exactly the same exposure times at the same time of year with similar temperatures and got results for removed carcasses that are relatively stable then you might model it as a Beta distribution and calculate the confidence intervals from that.

Comment: Carl, thank you very much again. Yes, at first, all conditions are the "same" along those years (2016-2020). I believe I understand your point. Could I model a beta regression relating the persistence rates (proportion carcasses that are not removed) and the actual number of carcasses found along the years? This way I could predict the persistence rates of the following years using the number of carcasses found in the field.

Comment: I need more information about your data to really say what might be best, at present, I am just guessing, so don't hold me to it. Maybe put what data you have in the question, now maybe you don't want to do that, but I don't see how to avoid it.

Comment: I do not have the raw data yet, I am going to get it in the next few days. When I have it I am going to post here. For now, do you think it make sense to predict persistence rates based on found carcasses using beta regression?

Comment: It only makes sense under special circumstances, which is why we need to know what the data is. It's just easier to write a procedure up when the data is available, otherwise the procedure is if this then that, and if not but if this other thing then that, then if....etc. In other words, giving you a book length answer would not help you much; too many if's.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I thought about it. The question is whether or not one can eliminate testing for missing carcasses. Assuming the annual testing is done under the same conditions, the null hypothesis is that there is no difference in the multiple proportions of missing carcasses on an annual basis.

**Method 1:** So we first have to know if the multiple proportions are the same. This can be done using the [Marascuillo procedure](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc464.htm). This is indeed an application of Chi-square.

Now, if these proportions are different, then we cannot do the next step that easily, which should make sense because we would have a harder time predicting a future proportion given one that is variable from year to year. Now if the proportions are truly the same, then we can just add up the numbers and make a single binomial proportion, e.g., 30 removed of 100, 14 removed of 46, etc., becomes 30+14... of 100+46..., and then calculate the 95% [confidence interval of that binomial proportion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval). That then expressed as a percentage result for 95% likely range, would suggest something like expected carcasse removal is expected to vary from some percentage, e.g., 28% to 35% with that occurring 95% of the time for a large number of carcasses (the total in the denominator), with that then serving as limits of anticipated carcasse percentage removal for a large population.

Now this is perhaps not the best approach in the sense that no proportion of this type can be assumed to be perfectly stable from year to year and thus the 95% confidence interval calculated might actually be a lower percentage confidence interval in practice, e.g., a 90% one, so one should either mention that the estimate is not conservative or to use some additional or even other procedure to refine the results. The way to phrase that is something like, "the range of percentages of carcass removal is from (made up numbers) 28% to 35% for at most a 95% confidence interval."

**Method 2** Above we assumed that we have to know that the proportion of removed carcasses is the same from year to year. However, there may be a way to remove this requirement entirely and instead only require that the proportion remain constant *within* each year's data, a much less severe assumption of stationarity. However, this might involve combining conditional probabilities of the several binomial distributions, and I am not quite sure, at the time of this writing, of just how to do that.